# Distance between set of lines

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

Say that my images are simple shapes - set of lines, dots, curves, and simple objects, 
How do I calculate the distance between images - so length is important but total scale is non important, location of line\curve is important, angles is important etc

Attached image For example:

My comparison object is a cube on the top left, score are fictitious just for this example.

1. that the distance to the Cylinder is 80 (has 2 lines but top geometry is different)
2. The bottom left cube score is 100 since it exact match lines with different scale.
3. The bottom right Rectangle score is 90 since it has exact match lines on the top but different scale lines on the side.

I am looking for algorithm name or general approach that will help me to start to think towards a solution....

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: You forgot to comment on a very important and crucial aspect of your question: how are these shapes obtained ? Do someone manually draw them ? Or, maybe, do you have a set of points that define the shape ? If the former, then you have a very hard problem that can only be approximated by guessing.

Comment: I will get The images by edge and line detection or by Hough Transform, The original image is a gray-scale of simple shapes cube circle triangle etc. so the transform output should (theoretically) match the original input

Comment: Fine, but I'm curious to see how you will handle arbitrarily lines using Hough :) If I have time later, I will tribute to contribute with some answer given your updated information.

Comment: I was thinking that arbitrarily lines and dots will be participates in the scoring mechanism, I don't know how exactly this will work, i need to look for algorithm name or approach.

Comment: I'm still curious on how you think you are going to handle arbitrary curved lines using Hough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something to get you started. When jumping into new problems, I don't see much value in trying a lot of complex steps just because they are available somewhere to use. So my focus is on using relatively simple things, that will fail in more varied situations, but hopefully you will see its value and get some sense of the problem.

The approach is fully based on corner detection; two typical methods for this detection are the Harris detector or the one by Shi and Tomasi described in the paper "Good Features to Track", 1994. I will use the second one, just because there is a ready implementation in OpenCV, newer Matlab, and possibly many other places. Its implementation on these packages also allows for easier parameter adjustment, regarding corner quality and minimum distance between corners. So, suppose you can detect all corner points correctly, how do you measure how close one shape is to another one based on these points ? The images have arbitrary size, so my idea is to normalize the point coordinates to the range [0, 1]. This solves for the scaling issue, which is desired according to the original description. Now we have to compare point sets in the range [0, 1]. Here we go for the simplest thing: consider one point `p` from the shape `a`, what is the closest point in shape `b` ? We assume it is one with the minimum absolute different between this point `p` and any point in `b`. If we sum all the values, we get a scoring between shapes. The lower the score, the more similar the shapes (according to this approach).

Here are some shapes I drew:

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Here are the detected corners:

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

As you can clearly see in this last set of images, the method will easily confuse a rectangle/square with a cylinder. To handle that you will need to combine the approach with other descriptors. Initially, a simple one that you might consider is the ratio between the shape's area and its bounding box area (which would give 1 for rectangle, and lower for cylinder).

With the method described above, here are the measurements between the first and second shapes, first and third shapes, ..., respectively: 0.02358485, 0.41350339, 0.30128458  0.4980852, 0.18031262. The second cube is a resized version of the first one, and as you see, they are very similar by this metric. The last shape is a resized version of the first cube but without keeping the aspect ratio, and the metric gives a much higher difference.

If you want to play with the code that performs this, here it is (in Python, depends on OpenCV, numpy):

```
import sys
import cv2 as cv
import numpy

inp = []
for fname in sys.argv[1:]:
    img_color = cv.imread(fname)
    img = cv.cvtColor(img_color, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    inp.append((img_color, img))

ptsets = []

# Corner detection parameters.
params = (
        200,  # max number of corners
        0.01, # minimum quality level of corners
        10,   # minimum distance between corners
)
# Params for visual circle markers.
circle_radii = 3
circle_color = (255, 0, 0)
for i, (img_color, img) in enumerate(inp):
    height, width = img.shape
    cornerMap = cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(img, *params)
    corner = numpy.array([c[0] for c in cornerMap])

    for c in corner:
        cv.circle(img_color, tuple(c), circle_radii, circle_color, -1)

    # Just to visually check for correct corners.
    cv.imwrite('temp_%d.png' % i, img_color)

    # Convert corner coordinates to [0, 1]
    cornerUnity = (corner - corner.min()) / (corner.max() - corner.min())
    # You might want to use other descriptors here. XXX
    ptsets.append(cornerUnity)


def compare_ptsets(p):
    res = numpy.zeros(len(p))

    base = p[0]
    for i in xrange(1, len(p)):
        sum_min_diff = sum(numpy.abs(p[i] - value).min() for value in base)
        res[i] = sum_min_diff

    return res

res = compare_ptsets(ptsets)
print res
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, arbitrary curved lines is indeed my problem.
How do you suggest to handle curved lines ?

Comment: Corner detection serves as a good starting point there too. After you detect the corners, you can easily split the lines. Now it depends on how arbitrary these curves are in fact. If I were solving this problem myself, with some own restrictions I have imposed in my head, I would probably perform spline approximations to relate how similar the lines in two figures are.

Answer (score 1):

The process to be followed depends on what depth of features you are going to consider and accuracy required.

If you want something more accurate, search some technical papers like [this](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sapphire/pubs/200388.pdf) which can give a concrete and well-proven approach or algorithm.

**EDIT:**

The idea from **Waltz algorithm** (one method in AI) can be tweaked. This is just my thought. Interpret the original image, generate some constraints out of it. For each candidate, find out the number of constraints it satisfies. The one which satisfies more constraints will be the most similar to the original image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to calculate [mass center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass) for each figure. Treat each point of figure as particle with mass equal 1.

Then calculate each distance as `sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)`, where (xi, yi) is mass center coordinate for figure i.

Comment: What do you do with those distances?